# Rails redirect with collection_select and javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a collection_select that fires some JS to set an id in my URL when the click occurs. Here is the code.

application.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#org_id").on("change", function(){
      val = $(this).val();
      window.location = '/sessions?org_id='+ val;
    });
});
```

view

```
<div id="org-select">
  <%= collection_select :org, :id, Org.all, :id, :name %>
</div>
```

rendered html

```
<div id="org-select">
  <select id="org_id" name="org[id]"><option value="1">bustas</option>
<option value="2">wintas</option></select>
```

What all of this does is give me a url like /sessions?org_id=2.

The issue I am having is that the select box in the page defaults to the first org, and when the user changes the option in the select, the page fires/refreshes, but the page defaults back to that first org, so the id in the URL does not change.

Comment: What about mounting your url using your server. By example window.location = 'http://yourserver.com/sessions?org_id='+ val;

Comment: Nope...adding the domain gives me the same behavior.

Comment: Your val variable is global, because you don't have used the var keyword. Try to use: var val = $(this).val(); I think that this will not fix, but is a good pratice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `collection_select` does have an option to set the default value. As you can see on the last example provided by some user here:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select

What you can do is set the selected value to the params you are getting from the url, something like this:

```
<%= collection_select :org, :id, Org.all, :id, :name, {:selected => params[:org_id]} %>
```

The `?org_id=2` part of the url is translated to `params[:org_id]` internally, so you can use it like the example above.
Give it a try and see if it works.

Comment: Thanx MurifoX, this fixed the issue, but I'm not sure how/why? Why was the page reloading in the first place?

Comment: In javascript, when you do a `window.location`, you tell the browser to make a request to this new URL.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use options_for_select. And give params[value] in selected area. Your code will be like:

Rails:

```
<%= select_tag "org_id", options_for_select(Org.all.collect{ |o| [o.name, o.id] }, {:selected => "#{params[:org_id] if params[:org_id].present?}"}), {} %>
```

Comment: This worked, so I gave you an upvote, but I selected MurifoX's answer as correct just because it was a little more succinct.